# XServer touchscreen one finger instead of two finger scrolling

Tags: linux, scrolling, chromium, touchscreen, x-server

**Problem:**

My *touchscreen* device does not scroll on touching it with *one* finger, which is desired, but only when touching it with *two* fingers.

**Technology stack:**

- Linux kernel 4.9.81-intel-pk-standard
- custom distro via yocto
- Xserver (X.Org X Server 1.19.3)
- QtWebEngine (Qt5.9)
- Chromium

**Further info:**

- I guess it is an Xserver Problem, since it's got to be Xserver or the web stuff, but I can rule out the web stuff because I can access the UI remotely from a desktop PC's chrome browser, use chrome's inspect function to simulate a touch device and scroll the UI with the simulated (single finger) touch.
- The two fingers need to be at least about 2cm apart so that scrolling works (this might be irrelevant)

Comment: Is it possible to set somehow one finger scrolling? I have an old screen which supports only that, but I think the same two finger scrolling is the default now. :S I cannot set anything from the menu, I hope there is a config file somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was wrong and it was not an Xserver problem, but a Qt / qml problem: The QQuickWidget representation of the window needed to accept Touch events.